# Halachic Works Western Sephardic and Portuguese Hahamim?

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, s-and-p-sephardi

I was wondering if anyone could recommend halachic works by the Hahamim of the Western Sephardic and Portuguese communities if any exist.

I am aware of such things like Keter Shem Tov which detail their minhagim, but I'm more interested in the halachic traditions reflected in local piskei halacha.

Comment: This may not be what you are looking for, but it is a very interesting sefer by Avraham Chaim Noeh, a Lubavitcher Chasid who was the secretary of Rabbi Yosef Chaim Zonnenfeld (Ashkenazi Rabbi of Jerusalem), it is a kitzur shulchan aruch style sefer based on Egyptian minhagim, and with a Judeo-Egyptian translation(!).http://www.hebrewbooks.org/35286

Answer (score 1):

Rabbi Joseph Dweck is the Senior Rabbi of the Spanish and Portuguese Congregation in the UK, and he has hundreds of shiurim on Halacha and many other topics, all freely available online. He is married to a granddaughter of Rabbi Ovadia Yosef. His website is www.mipazrav.com

Comment: Chaim, that link isn't to a valid domain.

Comment: Yes it is. Just clicked it myself.

Answer (score 0):

These links should give you plenty to work with...

http://seforimcenter.com/HEBREW-Books/Halacha/Sheelot-UTshuvot-/Sheelot-UTshuvot---Rabbeinu-Nissim-ben-Reuven__p-73-74-185-5099.aspx

http://seforimcenter.com/HEBREW-Books/Halacha/Sheelot-UTshuvot-/Sheelot-UTshuvot-HaRashba-5-vol.__p-73-74-185-3383.aspx

http://seforimcenter.com/HEBREW-Books/Halacha/Sheelot-UTshuvot-/Sheelot-UTshuvot-HaTashbetz--R-Shimon-bar-Tzemach-5-vol.__p-73-74-185-9338.aspx

http://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=10352&strReferer=search&PPGR=1

http://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=9348&strReferer=search&PPGR=7

http://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=9521&strReferer=search&PPGR=7

http://seforimcenter.com/Product.aspx?ProductID=9342&strReferer=search&PPGR=7

Comment: I assume he meant more recent writers. Furthermore, are the _Rashba_, _Ran_, and _Tashbetz_ Portugese and Western Spanish in particular? The Tashbetz was actually Algerian (although his family originated in Spain...)

Comment: Please clarify the nature of these works. Unexplained links are generally discouraged.

Comment: @mevaqesh, I made no assumptions about recent or older sources. But Rishonim are fine. All these are in the domain of 'western Sefardic'. As opposed to Egyptian or Syrian or Turkish.

Comment: And it's a pretty straightforward request. The OP wants book recommendations. Res Ipsa Loquitor.

Comment: And in fact, the OP's mention of "if they exist" implies they are looking for older sources.